# Does a passed final variable in Java stay final on the other side?

Tags: java, return-value, final, parameter-passing, constants

I've just come across some code that's confusing me slightly; there are really 2 variations that I'd like to clarify.

**Example 1:**

```
public String getFilepath(){
        final File file = new File(this.folder, this.filename);
        return file.getAbsolutePath();
    }
```

What would be the purpose of declaring `file` "`final`"? Since Java primitives are passed by value, and `getAbsolutePath()` is just returning a `String`, the variable won't be `final` on the other side (calling method), will it? And since the `file` variable only exists within the scope of these 2 lines, I can't really see any purpose of the `final` keyword. Is there something I'm missing? Anyone see a reason to do this?

**Example 2:**

```
public String getFilepath(){
        final File file = new File(this.folder, this.filename);
        return file;
    }
```

Since here the actual object is being returned... Does that mean the `file` variable will be constant/`final` on the other side...? It doesn't seem to make sense.

In general, it seems to me that you pass a variable, *without* it's access type. As in, I can have a `private` variable in a function with a `public` get function that returns it - but the variable that receives it by calling the function has to specify an access modifier. So if it specifies `public`, the returned variable will be `public` in that scope. If it specifies `private`, the returned variable will be `private` in that scope. Is there a difference with `final`? Is the "constancy" of a variable something that can be passed? This strikes me as rather improbable, considering what I know of Java.

Or am I missing the point entirely and there's some other purpose of the `final` keyword in the above code?

**Edit:**

I checked back with the original developer who wrote the code, and he said he only put the `final` keyword in because he had originally thought the method would be a lot longer and wanted to ensure that the file stayed constant throughout. He also said that he generally declares variables that should not be changed as `final`, as a rule across the board and sort of on principle - a point that both the answers below mentioned. So it seems I was reading too much into a simple extra keyword included for standards reasons. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some people might tell you that there's a performance benefit to using final, but that is, in no way, conclusively proven.

The primary benefit of the `final` keyword is for the programmer to indicate that a class, method, or field should not be changed.

Bear in mind that declaring a variable `final` does not make the referenced object immutable. It just means that the variable cannot have its value reassigned. You can still run methods of the variable `file` that could change the `File` object internally.

In the two methods you give, I see no value in making the `file` variable `final`. Some code conventions advocate making all variable `final` unless the need to be modified. Some people don't subscribe to that. I consider it a variation on the [precautionary principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precautionary_principle).

Comment: There are cases where using a final will definitely give you better performance, for instance using http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization.

Comment: @Stuart, you are confused.  Memoization optimizations are not related to the `final` keyword (though they can be used in conjunction in Java, the `final` keyword does not provide any of the Memoization pattern's inherent speed benefit).

Comment: OP's question was never answered.  Does a p̶a̶s̶s̶e̶d̶ returned final variable in Java stay final on the other side?

Answer (score 14):

`final` in this case just means that the local reference `file` will be immutable. It has no meaning outside the method. Some coding conventions advocate having all variables final unless they need to be mutable so you'll see code like that when someone is following such guidelines.

Comment: I know this is nitpicking... but I just wanted to mention that "immutable" might not be the best word choice, as all Strings are immutable in Java. I do get your point, though, regardless

Comment: I said the _reference_ file was immutable. I.e. you could not point 'file' to another 'File' object. That is exactly what the 'final' keyword means in Java. The reference can not be changed.  The word immutable just means something that can not be changed. It can be used in many contexts.